# cakephp-3 hasmany form data save

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, has-many

I have two tables resumes and links. resumes has hasmany relation with links.I want to save many links for single resume.

My $this->request->data array is like

```
Array
(
[alternate_email] => 
[mobile] => 23232
[level] => Student
[youtube] => 
[links] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                ['link'] => www.google.com
                ['user_id'] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                ['link'] => abc.com
                ['user_id'] => 1
            )

    )

)


$resume = $this->Resumes->newEntity($this->request->data);
if ($this->Resumes->save($resume)) {
// return true;
}
```

This is working and my data is saved in resumes table properly but in links table data saved like following:

```
id | resume_id | user_id  | link
1  | 1         |          |
```

I want like

```
id | resume_id | user_id | link
1  | 1         |         | www.google.com
```

Comment: In User table have you field `resume_id` or `user_id`?

Comment: In my resume table field user_id is exist.

Comment: You display user_id in array structure and in table format you are display resume_id will both same?

Comment: You really need to spice up your question with some details. Are you using the latest 3.x version? What do the generated queries look like? What does `debug($resume)` say before and after saving (please update your question with debugging results, don't put them here in the comments)? Any validation errors? Do you have any before save logic implemented? Why don't you want the `user_id` to be saved (as shown in your "_I want like_" example)?

Comment: Hi @ndm, I am working on 3.0.0 dev 3 version. You can see all details on link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cake-php/1-cA6i4--7c

Comment: Well, besides the fact that questions should be self contained, ie not dependent on external information, crosspostings are pretty impolite as someone somewhere is wasting his/her time on your question.

Answer (score 1):

try do that:

```
$resume = $this->Resumes->newEntity($this->request->data, ['associated' => ['Links']]);

if ($this->Resumes->save($resume, ['associated' => ['Links']])) {
    // return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `Model/Entity/Link.php` and add `link` to  `protected $_accessible` array